# Names of paragraphs, chapters, section etc. in Cyrillic

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, babel, sections-paragraphs, cyrillic

So I am doing some paper for school and I've been struggling to find how to do Cyrillic in LaTeX, now I cracked that part, but still can not find a way to write names of chapters, section etc. in Cyrillic...
I am only getting error in form of latex log(i.e. *open latex log*)

Anyway, here is what I did:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Увод}
%%...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code compiles for me without an error. What is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is essentially fine, but there are two fixes to be done.

1. Don't use `utf8x`, but `utf8` for `inputenc`.
2. Add the `unicode` option for `hyperref`, in order to get good bookmarks.
3. Issuing `\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont` is not necessary.

Here's the fixed code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <--- not utf8x
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  allcolors=blue,
  unicode, % <-- for correct bookmarks
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Увод}

%%...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, it actually works, finally, woah. Thank you, really! :-)